# create classes from xsd with multiple dependencies for c#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have an xsd which has 4 xsd dependencies. How can I create a class so I can use it in c#.
I tried with `xsd.exe /classes ef15.xsd types.xsd tms.xsd tcl.xsd doc.xsd`
but it gives me schema validation warnings.
I don't know if I can change something in the xsd so it can work because I am not familiar with xsd schemas.
I used the "generate code to XSD" tool in visual studio but it doesn't give me correct xml.

Here is the xsd file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ie="http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/ef15/ie" xmlns:emcs="http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/types" xmlns:tms="http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/tms" xmlns:tcl="http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/tcl" xmlns:doc="http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/doc" targetNamespace="http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/ef15/ie" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.03">
  <!--=========================================-->
  <!--===== EF15:N_DFK_SUB -->
  <!--===== Υποβολή ΔΕΦΚ -->
  <!--=========================================-->
  <!--===== Imports =====-->
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/types" schemaLocation="types.xsd" />
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/tms" schemaLocation="tms.xsd" />
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/tcl" schemaLocation="tcl.xsd" />
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/doc" schemaLocation="doc.xsd" />
  <!--===== Root Element =====-->
  <xs:element name="EF15A" type="ie:EF15AType" />
  <!--===== EMCS Data Groups Declarations =====-->
  <xs:complexType name="EF15AType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Header" type="tms:HeaderType" />
      <xs:element name="Body" type="ie:BodyType" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <!--===== IE Specific Data Groups Declarations =====-->
  <xs:complexType name="BodyType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="DeclarationOfExciseTaxesRegistration" type="ie:DeclarationOfExciseTaxesRegistrationType" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="DeclarationOfExciseTaxesRegistrationType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="SubmittingOperator" type="ie:SubmittingOperatorType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="ExciseTaxesDeclaration" type="ie:ExciseTaxesDeclarationType" />
      <xs:element name="ExciseTaxesDeclarationConsignor" type="ie:ExciseTaxesDeclarationConsignorType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="ExciseTaxesObligee" type="ie:ExciseTaxesObligeeType" />
      <xs:element name="ExciseTaxesDeclarationConsignee" type="ie:ExciseTaxesDeclarationConsigneeType" />
      <xs:element name="ExciseTaxesRow" type="ie:ExciseTaxesRowType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="SubmittingOperatorType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="SUBMITTING OPERATOR" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="SubmittingOperatorIdentification" type="emcs:SubmittingOperatorIdentificationType" />
      <xs:element name="SubmittingTraderIdentification" type="emcs:SubmittingTraderIdentificationType" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="ExciseTaxesDeclarationType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="EXCISE TAXES DECLARATION" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="LocalReferenceNumber" type="emcs:LocalReferenceNumberType" />
      <xs:element name="Fallbackflag" type="tcl:Flag" />
      <xs:element name="FallbackDocumentReference" type="emcs:FallbackDocumentReferenceType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="FallbackOffice" type="emcs:ExciseOfficeCodeType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="RegistrationDate" type="emcs:DateType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="RegistrationOffice" type="emcs:ExciseOfficeCodeType" />
      <xs:element name="DocumentState" type="tcl:DocumentStateCodes" />
      <xs:element name="DocumentNumber" type="emcs:DocumentNumberType" />
      <xs:element name="TotalDocuments" type="emcs:TotalDocumentsType" />
      <xs:element name="NumberOfRows" type="emcs:NumberOfRowsType" />
      <xs:element name="TotalPackages" type="emcs:TotalPackagesType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="FinancialResponsibleTaxId" type="emcs:FinancialResponsibleTaxIdType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="DispatchCountry" type="emcs:CountryCodeType" />
      <xs:element name="DestinationCountry" type="emcs:CountryCodeType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="ExistenceOfContainerFlag" type="tcl:Flag" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="DeliveryConditions" type="emcs:DeliveryConditionsType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="Currency" type="emcs:CurrencyType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="InvoiceAmount" type="emcs:InvoiceAmountType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="ExchangeFactor" type="emcs:ExchangeFactorType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="ChemicalAnalysisPerformedFlag" type="tcl:Flag" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="ThroughSimplifiedProcedureFlag" type="tcl:Flag" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="OfficeOfDispatch" type="emcs:ExciseOfficeCodeType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="PaymentMethodCode" type="tcl:PaymentMethodCodes" />
      <xs:element name="CertificateIssuanceFlag" type="tcl:Flag" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="DeclarationTypeCode" type="tcl:DeclarationTypeCodes" />
      <xs:element name="CalculationOfTaxesDate" type="emcs:DateType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="GeneralChemistryDetails" type="ie:GeneralChemistryDetailsType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="DeliveryDetails" type="ie:DeliveryDetailsType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="ClearingAgent" type="ie:ClearingAgentType" />
      <xs:element name="GuaranteeReference" type="ie:GuaranteeReferenceType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="2" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="GeneralChemistryDetailsType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="GENERAL CHEMISTRY DETAILS" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="SampleReference" type="emcs:SampleReferenceType" />
      <xs:element name="AnalysisReference" type="emcs:AnalysisReferenceType" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="DeliveryDetailsType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="DELIVERY DETAILS" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="TransportVehicleIdentificationNumber" type="emcs:TransportVehicleIdentificationNumberType" />
      <xs:element name="TransportVehicleCountry" type="emcs:CountryCodeType" />
      <xs:element name="NationalTransportMode" type="emcs:NationalTransportModeType" />
      <xs:element name="DipennakNumber" type="emcs:DipennakNumberType" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="ClearingAgentType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="CLEARING AGENT" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ClearingAgentType" type="tcl:ClearingAgentTypeCodes" />
      <xs:element name="ClearingAgentEORI" type="emcs:ClearingAgentEORIType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="ClearingAgentAfm" type="emcs:ClearingAgentAfmType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="SpecialReferenceCode" type="emcs:SpecialReferenceCodeType" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="GuaranteeReferenceType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="GUARANTEE REFERENCE" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="GuaranteeReferenceNumber" type="emcs:GuaranteeReferenceNumberType" />
      <xs:element name="GuaranteeAmount" type="emcs:GuaranteeAmountType" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="ExciseTaxesDeclarationConsignorType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="EXCISE TAXES DECLARATION CONSIGNOR" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ExciseTaxesDeclarationConsignorType" type="tcl:ExciseTaxesDeclarationConsignorTypeCodes" />
      <xs:element name="TaxOrVehicleWarehouseReference" type="emcs:TaxOrVehicleWarehouseReferenceType" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="ExciseTaxesObligeeType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="EXCISE TAXES OBLIGEE" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ObligeeType" type="tcl:ExciseTaxesObligeeTypeCodes" />
      <xs:element name="ObligeeIdentificationType" type="tcl:PersonIdentificationTypeCodes" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="ObligeeIdentification" type="emcs:ObligeeIdentificationType" />
      <xs:element name="ContactDetails" type="ie:ContactDetailsType" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="ContactDetailsType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="CONTACT DETAILS" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="LastNames" type="emcs:LastNamesType" />
      <xs:element name="Forenames" type="emcs:ForenamesType" />
      <xs:element name="NameOfFather" type="emcs:NameOfFatherType" />
      <xs:element name="Address" type="emcs:AddressType" />
      <xs:element name="Country" type="emcs:CountryCodeType" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="ExciseTaxesDeclarationConsigneeType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="EXCISE TAXES DECLARATION CONSIGNEE" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ConsigneeType" type="tcl:ExciseTaxesConsignee" />
      <xs:element name="ConsigneeIdentificationType" type="tcl:PersonIdentificationTypeCodes" />
      <xs:element name="ConsigneeIdentification" type="emcs:ConsigneeIdentificationType" />
      <xs:element name="ContactDetails" type="ie:ContactDetailsType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="SpecialConsignee" type="ie:SpecialConsigneeType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="VesselRegistrationDetails" type="ie:VesselRegistrationDetailsType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="ComplementaryConsignees" type="ie:ComplementaryConsigneesType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="99" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="SpecialConsigneeType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="SPECIAL CONSIGNEE" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="SpecialConsigneeLicenseType" type="tcl:SpecialConsigneeLicenseTypeCodes" />
      <xs:element name="SpecialConsigneeLicenseNumber" type="emcs:DeclarationReferenceNumberType" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="VesselRegistrationDetailsType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="VESSEL REGISTRATION DETAILS" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="VesselRegistrationType" type="tcl:VesselRegistrationTypeCodes" />
      <xs:element name="VesselRegistrationNumber" type="emcs:VesselRegistrationNumberType" />
      <xs:element name="VesselName" type="emcs:VesselNameType" />
      <xs:element name="VesselPortOfRegistration" type="emcs:VesselPortOfRegistrationType" />
      <xs:element name="VesselIMO" type="emcs:VesselIMOType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="VesselCountryOfOrigin" type="emcs:CountryCodeType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="VesselCategory" type="emcs:VesselCategoryType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="VesselCapacity" type="emcs:VesselCapacityType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="VesselHorsePower" type="emcs:VesselHorsePowerType" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="ComplementaryConsigneesType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="COMPLEMENTARY CONSIGNEES" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ComplementaryConsigneeIdentificationType" type="tcl:PersonIdentificationTypeCodes" />
      <xs:element name="ComplementaryConsigneeIdentification" type="emcs:ComplementaryConsigneeIdentificationType" />
      <xs:element name="ExemptionBeneficiaryFlag" type="tcl:Flag" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="OwnershipPercentage" type="emcs:OwnershipPercentageType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="ContactDetails" type="ie:ContactDetailsType" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="ExciseTaxesRowType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="EXCISE TAXES ROW" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ExciseTaxesDeclarationRowNumber" type="emcs:ExciseTaxesDeclarationRowNumberType" />
      <xs:element name="SymbolNumbers" type="emcs:SymbolNumbersType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="ProductDescription" type="emcs:ProductDescriptionType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="TaricCode" type="emcs:TaricCodeType" />
      <xs:element name="TaricAdditionCode" type="emcs:TaricAdditionCodeType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="TaxQuantity" type="emcs:TaxQuantityType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="MeasuringUnitsType" type="emcs:MeasuringUnitsTypeType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="AdditionalTaxQuantity" type="emcs:AdditionalTaxQuantityType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="AdditionalMeasuringUnits" type="emcs:AdditionalMeasuringUnitsType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="Plato" type="emcs:PlatoType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="EtepaaAmountPaid" type="emcs:EtepaaAmountPaidType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="ExciseTaxCompensation" type="emcs:ExciseTaxCompensationType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="VatAmountCompensation" type="emcs:VatAmountCompensationType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="VatInflowAmountCompensation" type="emcs:VatInflowAmountCompensationType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="OgaAmountCompensation" type="emcs:OgaAmountCompensationType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="TaxValue" type="emcs:TaxValueType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="CountryOfOrigin" type="emcs:CountryCodeType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="GrossWeight" type="emcs:GrossWeightType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="NetWeight" type="emcs:NetWeightType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="ConditionIdentification" type="tcl:ConditionIdentificationCodes" />
      <xs:element name="PreviousConditionIdentification" type="tcl:PreviousConditionIdentificationCodes" />
      <xs:element name="ExemptionCode" type="emcs:ExemptionCodeType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="NetValue" type="emcs:NetValueType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="StatisticalValue" type="emcs:StatisticalValueType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="SuspensionTypeCode" type="emcs:SuspensionTypeCodeType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="CarCertificate" type="emcs:CarCertificateType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="SupplementaryComputationInformation" type="ie:SupplementaryComputationInformationType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="99" />
      <xs:element name="PreviousDocuments" type="ie:PreviousDocumentsType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="ReferenceDocuments" type="ie:ReferenceDocumentsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="3" />
      <xs:element name="NationalProducts" type="ie:NationalProductsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element name="VehicleDetails" type="ie:VehicleDetailsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element name="TaxComputation" type="ie:TaxComputationType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element name="SpecialMentions" type="ie:SpecialMentionsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="99" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="SupplementaryComputationInformationType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="SUPPLEMENTARY COMPUTATION INFORMATION" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="SupplementaryComputationInfo" type="emcs:SupplementaryComputationInfoType" />
      <xs:element name="SupplementaryComputationValue" type="emcs:SupplementaryComputationValueType" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="PreviousDocumentsType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="PREVIOUS DOCUMENTS" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="PreviousDocumentType" type="tcl:PreviousDocumentTypeCodes" />
      <xs:element name="PreviousAsdeDocument" type="ie:PreviousAsdeDocumentType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="PreviousEaadDocument" type="ie:PreviousEaadDocumentType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="PreviousStampRequestDocument" type="ie:PreviousStampRequestDocumentType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="PreviousVehicleArrivalDocument" type="ie:PreviousVehicleArrivalDocumentType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="PreviousVehicleMovementDocument" type="ie:PreviousVehicleMovementDocumentType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="PreviousExciseTaxesDeclarationDocument" type="ie:PreviousExciseTaxesDeclarationDocumentType" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="PreviousAsdeDocumentType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="PREVIOUS ASDE DOCUMENT" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="AsdeReferenceNumber" type="emcs:AsdeReferenceNumberType" />
      <xs:element name="AsdeRowNumber" type="emcs:AsdeRowNumberType" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="PreviousEaadDocumentType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="PREVIOUS E-AAD DOCUMENT" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="AadReferenceCode" type="emcs:AadReferenceCodeType" />
      <xs:element name="SequenceNumber" type="emcs:SequenceNumberType" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="PreviousStampRequestDocumentType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="PREVIOUS STAMP REQUEST DOCUMENT" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="DeclarationReferenceNumber" type="emcs:DeclarationReferenceNumberType" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="PreviousVehicleArrivalDocumentType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="PREVIOUS VEHICLE ARRIVAL DOCUMENT" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="DeclarationReferenceNumber" type="emcs:DeclarationReferenceNumberType" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="PreviousVehicleMovementDocumentType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="PREVIOUS VEHICLE MOVEMENT DOCUMENT" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="DeclarationReferenceNumber" type="emcs:DeclarationReferenceNumberType" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="PreviousExciseTaxesDeclarationDocumentType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="PREVIOUS EXCISE TAXES DECLARATION DOCUMENT" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="DeclarationReferenceNumber" type="emcs:DeclarationReferenceNumberType" />
      <xs:element name="ExciseTaxesDeclarationRowNumber" type="emcs:ExciseTaxesDeclarationRowNumberType" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="ReferenceDocumentsType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="REFERENCE DOCUMENTS" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ReferenceDocumentId" type="emcs:ReferenceDocumentIdType" />
      <xs:element name="ReferenceDocumentNumber" type="emcs:ReferenceDocumentNumberType" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="NationalProductsType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="NATIONAL PRODUCTS" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="NationalProductId" type="emcs:NationalProductIdType" />
      <xs:element name="Quantity" type="emcs:QuantityType" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="VehicleDetailsType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="VEHICLE DETAILS" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="FrameNumber" type="emcs:FrameNumberType" />
      <xs:element name="CarKind" type="emcs:CarKindType" />
      <xs:element name="ImporterCodeOrBrandName" type="emcs:ImporterCodeOrBrandNameType" />
      <xs:element name="FirstAllowanceDate" type="emcs:DateType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="VehicleFactoryType" type="emcs:VehicleFactoryTypeType" />
      <xs:element name="VehicleUsedFlag" type="tcl:Flag" />
      <xs:element name="EngineCapacity" type="emcs:EngineCapacityType" />
      <xs:element name="EngineType" type="emcs:EngineTypeType" />
      <xs:element name="FuelType" type="emcs:FuelTypeType" />
      <xs:element name="MakeYear" type="emcs:MakeYearType" />
      <xs:element name="VehicleModelName" type="emcs:VehicleModelNameType" />
      <xs:element name="ImportedDate" type="emcs:DateType" />
      <xs:element name="CountryLast" type="emcs:CountryCodeType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="ApprovalCodeVehicle" type="emcs:ApprovalCodeVehicleType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="ApprovalCodeFactory" type="emcs:ApprovalCodeFactoryType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="ApprovalCodeType" type="emcs:ApprovalCodeTypeType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="VehicleRebateFlag" type="tcl:Flag" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="RebatedVehicleRegistrationPlate" type="emcs:RebatedVehicleRegistrationPlateType" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="VehicleInventory" type="ie:VehicleInventoryType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="99" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="VehicleInventoryType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="VEHICLE INVENTORY" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="VehicleInventoryType" type="emcs:VehicleInventoryTypeType" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TaxComputationType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="TAX COMPUTATION" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="NationalAccountingCode" type="emcs:NationalAccountingCodeType" />
      <xs:element name="SuspensionFlag" type="emcs:SuspensionFlagType" />
      <xs:element name="AmountOfTaxes" type="emcs:AmountOfTaxesType" />
      <xs:element name="PaymentMethodCode" type="emcs:PaymentMethodCodeType" />
      <xs:element name="TaxBase" type="emcs:TaxBaseType" />
      <xs:element name="TaxRate" type="emcs:TaxRateType" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="SpecialMentionsType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="SPECIAL MENTIONS" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="AdditionalInformationCoded" type="emcs:AdditionalInformationCodedType" />
      <xs:element name="Text" type="emcs:TextType" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**EDIT:** My main problem with the XSD is that it gets some deafult values which I need them in some cases but in generally i don't want to get any values.
For example ExciseTaxesDeclarationConsignorType is always gets value "0" even if I don't call it.
It get it's types from tcl.XSD

```
<xs:simpleType name="ExciseTaxesDeclarationConsignorTypeCodes">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Excise Taxes Declaration Consignor Type Codes</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:nonNegativeInteger">
      <xs:enumeration value="0">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>Tax Warehouse</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="1">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>Car Warehouse</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:enumeration>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Can I change that behaviour ?

Comment: Do you really need to use the XSD? If you generate an XSD from existing XML samples, you probably will need a lot of postprocessing to make the XSD correct. If you want to use XML in C# programs, Teh XML Linq classes are best choice in 99% of the cases (based on my experience). If you google on C# XDocument  you will find a lot of good examples and tutorials. It takes some time to learn, but then it works fast.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out because the truth is that the xsd contains some types which I don't want to get default values and if I use it as sxhema it will ruin my XML.

Comment: I went to the URL.  The schema is being upgraded to 3.3 and won't be available until the 15th.  It looks like you are using version 1.03.  So I suspect you are using a very old version of the xsd and need to use a newer version.  It is a Greek webpage.  You can register at following location which may have more info on the correct version to use : https://portal.gsis.gr/portal/page/portal/ICISnet/mainfullstory?sid=10590447

Comment: @jdweng There are no other versions of the XSD so far. They have change some of the XSD but not the one I want. This was done in 15 February.

Comment: My main problem with the specific XSD is that it gets some dfault values . For example the ExciseTaxesDeclarationConsignor it always get value 0 even if I don't call it. Can I somehow prevent this?

Comment: The issue is the TYPE URL page (namespace) isn't being found which is creating warnings.  Replace the version of the URL will remove the warnings and build all the classes.  Right now you are missing some classes because the xsd could not find the URL.  You need the correct URL.  The only temporary solution is to build manually the missing classes.  The xsd will build classes from the xml if you do not have the schema.

Comment: @jdweng this is happening when I run the xsd.exe tool. If I run the "generate code from XSD" it doesnt give me errors but I can't find why it gives me default values to some elements even if I don't call them at all.

Comment: The properties are in the schema show they show up in the classes even though they may be optional.

Comment: @jdweng I don't mean that there are properties that are created in class. I mean that some values of the XSD (as I write in my question) are get default values (usually 0)  which I don't call them to create. The problem is when those elements get values the program expects to give some other parameters.

Comment: Is those requirements for other items to exist in the schema or in your code?

Comment: Yes there are some rarely occasions that I may need to use those items. I just want to take values only when I call them.