# Cannot send correct SOAP message in c#

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I am trying to send a SOAP Message to a server using c# with XML body.

I know that I send the correct informations because I use the provided xsd to create the XML but it always gives me an error that it missing a field.

I tried to fix that but the technicians in the server side cannot help me (because they are ignorant).

I gave them the exact soap message that I have and they could send it from their side with a custom made program that they have(and cannot give it for testing).

I have both soap messages but I cannot find out what is wrong.

The main difference is that c# encodes the xml string to <$gt; etc while the other program send it as xml.

I tried to change it by hand and send it again but then it gives me error "xml element is invalid, its class is java.lang.string"

I tried to decode the xml message using

```
xml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(xml);
```

and changing

```
isXmlString = true
to 
isXmlString = false
```

as they have in their SOAP message
but it still returns xml syntax errors

The communication with the server is correct because I send many other messages and everything workd fine , excepts this one.

This is a link with 2 files
https://www.dropbox.com/t/syccgWiLz16iPP5n
the one is the SOAP Message from my program and the other is from their program.

Can someone help me what am I doing wrong?

After @jdweng comments we are focus on error with xsd and generated XML file. I am using xsd2code to generate the class and perhaps this is the poblem.
In this link there is the original xsd and the .cs file that containes the generated classes.
@jdweng suggest that I must create a dictionary to make a map with the corect node namespaces.
https://www.dropbox.com/t/asotnXFoxYs2fg6Y

EDIT:
Just to elaborate a little more on the way that I am sendng the SOAP message after @jdweng answer.
The whole proccess that I am using is

```
    EmcsMessage emcs = new EmcsMessage(DefkCurrent);
    EF15 ef15Msg = emcs.CreateEF15(); 
service.SubmitNTCS(ef15Msg, new IcisNetSecurityToken
                        {
                            DiasafistisAfm = DefkCurrent.Diasafistis.Afm,
                            Afm = DefkCurrent.ApostoleasYpoxreos.Afm,
                            IcisPassword = "xxxxxxx",
                            IcisUsername = "xxxxxxx",
                            WebServicePassword = "xxxxxxx",
                            WebServiceUsername = "xxxxxxx"
                        }, MessageTypeIcisNet.EF15);
```

EF15 is a class that uses EF15AType o create the whole message based on XSD

```
public EF15(Defk defk)
        {
            DefkCurrent = defk;
            MessageIF15 = new EF15AType();
            LengthWarn.WarnBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        }
```

Here is a little part of the EF15AType converted with xsd2Code

```
     [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.8.4084.0")]
        [System.SerializableAttribute()]
        [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/ef15/ie")]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("EF15A", Namespace = "http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/ef15/ie", IsNullable = false)]
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name = "EF15AType", Namespace = "http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/ef15/ie")]
        public partial class EF15AType
        {
    
            private HeaderType headerField;
    
            private BodyType bodyField;
    
            private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer;
    
            public EF15AType()
            {
                this.bodyField = new BodyType();
                this.headerField = new HeaderType();
            }
    
            [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
            public HeaderType Header
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.headerField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.headerField = value;
                }
            }
    .
.
.
etc
```

This method is for creating the XML Message and call the method to send it with this code:

```
public void SubmitNTCS(string documentXml, IcisNetSecurityToken token, MessageTypeIcisNet type)
   {
using (MessageProcessorPortTypeClient client = new MessageProcessorPortTypeClient())
            {
               client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "xxxxxxx";
                client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "xxxxxxx";

                MessageSubmissionRequest req = new MessageSubmissionRequest
                {
                    DigitallySignedMessage = new SubmittedXMLMessageInfo
                    {
                        isXmlString = false,
                        messageType = MessageHelper.GetTestMessageType(type),
                        xmlMessage = documentXml
                    },
                    wsUserID = "xxxxxxx",
                    wsPass = "xxxxxxx"
                };

                client.Open();

                MessageSubmissionRequestResult result = client.processIncomingMessage(req);
             }
    }
```

Before I send the message the documentXml is in form

```
<xmlMessage >
                        <EF15A:EF15A xmlns="http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/ef15/ie"
                                     xmlns:EF15A="http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/ef15/ie"
                                     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                            <Header>
.
.
.
etc
```

I am using fiddler to capture the communication between my program and the server and I see that when it makes the request to server it changes the  to

```
<xmlMessage xsi:type="xsd:string">&lt;EF15A xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/ef15/ie"&gt;&#xD;
  &lt;Header&gt;&#xD;
    &lt;MessageSender xmlns="http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/tms"&gt;TRADER.GR&lt;/MessageSender&gt;&#xD;
    &lt;MessageRecipient xmlns="http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/tms"&gt;NES.EL&lt;/MessageRecipient&gt;&#xD;
    &lt;DateOfPreparation xmlns="http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/tms"&gt;2023-09-25&lt;/DateOfPreparation&gt;&#xD;
    &lt;TimeOfPreparation xmlns="http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/tms"&gt;09:16:23&lt;/TimeOfPreparation&gt;&#xD;
    &lt;MessageIdentifier xmlns="http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/tms"&gt;23/71074&lt;/MessageIdentifier&gt;&#xD;
  &lt;/Header&gt;&#xD;
```

So it adds a type xsi:type="xsd:string" (which I haven't found where does it created) and changes everything to < >  etc

I assume that the xsi:type="xsd:string" is created in this part of the class that is created by WCF (Tha name is reference.cs and it says that it's auto-generated by a tool)

```
  [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.8.4084.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://icis.externaldomain.services.ws/common")]
    public partial class SubmittedXMLMessageInfo : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
        
        private object xmlMessageField;
        
        private MessageType messageTypeField;
        
        private bool isXmlStringField;
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
        public object xmlMessage {
            get {
                return this.xmlMessageField;
            }
            set {
                this.xmlMessageField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("xmlMessage");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public MessageType messageType {
            get {
                return this.messageTypeField;
            }
            set {
                this.messageTypeField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("messageType");
            }
        }
       etc...
```

EDIT 2:
I attached 2 more files which is the original XSD ef15 and the generated .cs file with xsd2code
[EF15 Files](https://www.dropbox.com/t/33gh33z0Lp6GNo3I)

Comment: Use an XML validator, what is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` doing in the middle of your file?

Comment: @Eelke Yes you are right. I had already remove that but it didnt work .  I accidentaly put it again in the file that I upload

Comment: There is definitely something wrong in your message because  `<DigitallySignedMessage messageType="EMCS_EF15"                             isXmlString="true"  xmlns="">` shouldn't be in the empty namespace. And as we can't see how the message gets constructed we can only guess what might be wrong. Were you given a WSDL file? Did you use svcutil to generate a wcf client and config their binding? You do use WCF, right?

Comment: @rene yes I am using WCF and xsd schema  to create the message and that's why I don't know why it doesn't pass the message correct. I am using WCF for the other messages as well(in the same server with the same way) and it works with no problems

Comment: Creating an xml using a schema doesn't mean the xml is going to validate against the schema.  The error is in the node xmlMessage.  Your node is missing the names space.  The working file has EF15A:EF15A while your file has EF15A.  I'm getting a warning : Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning  The element 'xmlMessage' cannot contain child element 'http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/ef15/ie:EF15A' because the parent element's content model is text only. ConsoleApp2 C:\Users\joel\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\XMLFile1.xml 27

Comment: @jdweng thanks for your answer. How can I fix this? Now I am using the xsd so I thought that everything is ok. I am using xsd2 code to create methods and then use them, I don't write every line in XML by hand

Comment: XSD will work correctly when you deserialize.  When serializer you have to add XmlSerializerNamespaces to your code for each namespace in the xml.  See the answer with 123 points : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339782/xml-serialization-and-namespace-prefixes

Comment: The Xsd tool puts URL namespace into the classes, but does not add the prefix.  You need to create a dictionary that contains both the prefix and URL for each namespace.  The XmlSerializerNamespaces is the dictionary that the xml serializer uses to map the URL to the prefix.

Comment: @jdweng Can you give me an example based on my files? I am not familiar working with xsd and xml. I thought using xsd2code will do the work.
If I understand correct I must put ns2: EF15A: wsse: etc but I can understand how can I do the mapping

Comment: @jdweng I have edit my question with two more files which are the original xsd and the generated from xsd2code. Can you give me an example of your solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.  Prefixes and namespace should look like their program xml

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\myprogram.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("S", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
            ns.Add("wsse", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
            ns.Add("wsu", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
            ns.Add("ns2", "http://icis.externaldomain.services.ws");
            ns.Add("EF15A", "http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/ef15/ie");
            //default namespace
            ns.Add(string.Empty, "http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/ef15/ie");

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            XmlSerializer xser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));

            Envelope envelope = new Envelope()
            {
                header = new Header()
                {
                    security = new Security()
                    {
                        mustUnderstand = 1,
                        UsernameToken = new UsernameToken()
                        {
                            Id = "unt_NWDbbtQj1OItWS1v",
                            Username = "xxxxxxxxx",
                            Password = new Password() { Type = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText", text = "xxxxxxxxx" },
                            Nonce = new Nonce() { EncodingType = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary", text = "BUgBcrQ7/cCru27bLjECNyKqqiy2fOG/WFCq6UBBpXs=" },
                            Created = DateTime.Now.ToString()
                        },
                        Timestamp = new Timestamp() { Created = DateTime.Now.ToString(), Expired = DateTime.Now.ToString() }
                    }
                },
                body = new Body()
                {
                    processIncomingMessageRequest = new processIncomingMessageRequest()
                    {
                        messageRequest = new messageRequest()
                        {
                            traderID = "120087250",
                            wsPass = "xxxxxxxxx",
                            wsUserID = "xxxxxxxxx",
                            DigitallySignedMessage = new DigitallySignedMessage()
                            {
                                isXmlString = false,
                                messageType = "EMCS_EF15",
                                xmlMessage = new xmlMessage() {
                                    MessageSender = "TRADER.GR",
                                    MessageRecipient = "NES.EL",
                                    DateOfPreparation = "2023-09-25",
                                    TimeOfPreparation = "09:16:23",
                                    MessageIdentifier = "23/71074",
                                    EF15A = new EF15A() }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            };

            xser.Serialize(writer, envelope, ns);

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Header", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public Header header { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public Body body { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Header", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Header
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Security", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
        public Security security { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Security", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
    public class Security
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "mustUnderstand", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public int mustUnderstand { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "UsernameToken", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
        public UsernameToken UsernameToken { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Timestamp", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd")]
        public Timestamp Timestamp { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "UsernameToken", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
    public class UsernameToken
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Id", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Username", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Password", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
        public Password Password { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Nonce", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
        public Nonce Nonce { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Created", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd")]
        public string Created { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Password", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
    public class Password
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Type", Namespace = "http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/ef15/ie")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string text { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Nonce", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
    public class Nonce
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "EncodingType", Namespace = "http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/ef15/ie")]
        public string EncodingType { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string text { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Timestamp", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
    public class Timestamp
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Created", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd")]
        public string Created { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Expired", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
        public string Expired { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "processIncomingMessageRequest", Namespace = "http://icis.externaldomain.services.ws")]
        public processIncomingMessageRequest processIncomingMessageRequest { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "processIncomingMessageRequest", Namespace = "http://icis.externaldomain.services.ws")]
    public class processIncomingMessageRequest
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "messageRequest", Namespace = "http://icis.externaldomain.services.ws")]
        public messageRequest messageRequest { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "messageRequest", Namespace = "http://icis.externaldomain.services.ws")]
    public class messageRequest
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "traderID", Namespace = "")]
        public string traderID { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "wsPass", Namespace = "")]
        public string wsPass { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "wsUserID", Namespace = "")]
        public string wsUserID { get; set; }


        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DigitallySignedMessage", Namespace = "")]
        public DigitallySignedMessage DigitallySignedMessage { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DigitallySignedMessage", Namespace = "")]
    public class DigitallySignedMessage
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "isXmlString", Namespace = "http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/ef15/ie")]
        public Boolean isXmlString { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "messageType", Namespace = "http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/ef15/ie")]
        public string messageType { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "xmlMessage", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
        public xmlMessage xmlMessage { get; set; }
    }
    public class xmlMessage
    {
        public string MessageSender { get; set; }
        public string MessageRecipient { get; set; }
        public string DateOfPreparation { get; set; }
        public string TimeOfPreparation { get; set; }
        public string MessageIdentifier { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "EF15A", Namespace = "http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/ef15/ie")]
        public EF15A EF15A { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "EF15A", Namespace = "http://www.icisnet.gr/emcs/v1.03/ef15/ie")]
    public class EF15A
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: What does Envelope should do? I can't understand it.

Comment: Envelope is the root element in the XML file.

Comment: ok now I get it.
 This code writes a myprogram.txt file with the code that I will provide and it will create a new node when I will use the classes (envelope , header ,security etc). 
Can I fix something in my code because I don't want to write every line to create the XML. 
Can I replace for example when there is an EF15A to add EF15A:EF15A

Comment: There are lot of things wrong.  Your code is too complicated.  Not sure why you have serialize method in all your classes.  You are missing schema.  I tried running xsd.exe on your schema and there are lots of errors.  The import schema at to of your xml are missing.  I suspect their file is not fully working.  Some of the prefixes may not match the schemas.

Comment: Yes I know, I tried to contact someone in charge there but nobody knows how to make it work. They have diferent programs that they work and they don't care if external users can't work. This xsd is for sending papers to custom services and they already have an online program for users. The whole problem as I see it starts from the <xmlMessage> node and below. In envelope, username,security etc before that node everything is correct.

Comment: I would make sure your xml works with the schema without any modifications.  The sample xml you got is wrong.  Their example has two headers and two bodies which is wrong.  I would use the xsd tool to generate your classes and then use class to serialize like my example.  I found the missing schema at the following two web pages : https://www.aade.gr/teloneia/version-123-01102023 and https://docs.oasis-open.org/  My sample code above is correct for the top section of the SOAP.

Comment: After some tests based on your code and your answers I found that the only problem sending this message is this line <xmlMessage xsi:type="xsd:string"> and that when I send the message the <xmlmessage> node changes the characters "<" and ">" with &lt &gt which I tried to change them with WebUtility.HtmlEncode(documentXml) but it keeps sending them as &lt &gt. Do you have any idea how to fix hose two problems?

Comment: The angle brackets are being considered inner text and not the normal angle brackets in xml.  The type attribute is used in the net library when an item is an inherited class.  You use XmlInclude on these properties.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute?view=net-7.0  The type should be a class and not a string.

Comment: I add some more details so maybe you understand a little more what I do to send the message and maybe how can I fix the problem. I don't think it's my problem because I already send them different messages in the same server with the same way. It has something to do with the specific message but they can't help me so I have to go with their way and change the way I send it.

Comment: Why are you embedding in the xmlMessage innertext raw xml (already has the angle brackets)?  You need to add an XmlElement (not text) to xmlMessage.  You can get an XmlElement from XML by using the parse method.  Then adding the XmlElement to the xmlMessage.

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't unsterstand. I am new to this kind of coding with XML , XSD etc and I don't know what should I change. Can you give me an example or if you wan't  more files and check if there is something there that I shold change.

Comment: Look at my code.  I only call the xmlserialize on the root xml (Envelope).  Then the class tree structure adds all the children.  You are serializing the xmlMessage and then taking the serialized string (contains the tags) and adding to the xmlMessage class.  This is the issue : LengthWarn.WarnBuilder = new StringBuilder();   All you need to do is to add MessageIF15 to my class property public EF15A EF15A.  You do not need to make it a string.  It should be public EF15A EF15A = MessageIF15

Comment: Should be : EF15AType EF15A = MessageIF15

Comment: Yes but the EF15 is another class that I seperate some of EF15AType into sections for example header,basic details etc.

Comment: The StringBuilder is the cause of the issue.  It is taking the XML and converting to a string.  You need to add a class object (not a string).  Look at my example.  The properties of the EF15AType is what you need.  If you do not want some of the properties to be in the Xml simply remove public.  Only public properties get serialized.

Comment: I tried to create the XML by hand with Xdocument and with EF15AType but I always get error "System.InvalidOperationException:  The type EF15AType was not expected.Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically" when I try to send the message to the server.

Comment: Do you have the class that the XSD.EXE generated?  Does the class inherit a base class?  You are missing the attribute XmlInclude.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute?view=net-7.0  When you have a inherited class the xml node with contain a TYPE attribute.

Comment: I attached 2 files , the original XSD and the xsd2code generated file. If you can help me make some modifications to the generated file so it doesnt add the xsi:type="xsd:string" to xmlMessage . I have no idea what I suppose to change

Comment: The issue is not in the files you posted.  It is where the EF15AType is referenced in the rest of the code.   This line looks wrong : MessageIF15 = new EF15AType();  How can you assign EF15AType to MessageIF15 unless it is an inherited class?  You are having an issue with the inheritance.

Comment: I have found two posting with similar EF15 issues.  One I gave a response in 2018 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64087384/how-can-i-find-the-parameters-of-a-wsdl-service-in-c-sharp
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206761/create-classes-from-xsd-with-multiple-dependencies-for-c-sharp

Comment: Those posts are from me. I couldn't find a solution then. Now with your help I am a little closer. As for the MessageIF15 it is private EF15AType MessageIF15 { get; set; }

Comment: Do you have any inherited classes?  Is it a compiler error?  Did you try to change private to public?

Comment: I noticed that when I read the documentXml there is no  xsi:type="xsd:string" and there is no &lt; &gt; characters. After it sends the message and makes the communication with   using (MessageProcessorPortTypeClient client = new MessageProcessorPortTypeClient())
            { ... rest of code it adds the  xsi:type="xsd:string" and the characters

Comment: I think these two lines are the issue : isXmlString = false,
                        messageType = MessageHelper.GetTestMessageType(type),  If you already have tags in the xml then it should be true.  What is the type?  It should be in the calling method typeof(MessageTypeIcisNet.EF15)

Comment: I figured out what is causing the XmlInclude error : public void SubmitNTCS(string documentXml, IcisNetSecurityToken token, MessageTypeIcisNet type).  The code is casting MessageTypeIcisNet.EF15 (the call to the method) to MessageTypeIcisNet

Comment: no, this is just to pass the correct message type as parameter . This is a public enum` "public enum MessageTypeIcisNet
    {
        IE515,
        IE507,
        IE513,EF15 etc.."

Comment: It is an enum or an inherited class?  It is causing the XmlInclude (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute?view=net-7.0) error.  With XML serialization you have a base class and an inherited class.  Adding the XmlInclude to your classes will get rid of error.  But it will also add a type attribute.  Check method MessageHelper.GetTestMessageType(type) and see how type is being used.  I suspect it is the type in a xml serialize statement and not a enum.  There must be an inherited class in the method.

Comment: The GetTestMessageType is just a method which return the correct type of the message. I use this in every type of message . internal static MessageProcessorServiceTest.MessageType GetTestMessageType(MessageTypeIcisNet type)  { switch (type) { case MessageTypeIcisNet.IE507:
                    return MessageProcessorServiceTest.MessageType.ECS_IE507;
                case MessageTypeIcisNet.IE515:
                    return MessageProcessorServiceTest.MessageType.ECS_IE515;
etc...}

Comment: and the MessageType " [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.8.9037.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://icis.externaldomain.services.ws/common")]
    public enum MessageType {
        
        /// <remarks/>
        NCTS_IE015,
        
        /// <remarks/>
        NCTS_IE224,
        
        /// <remarks/>
        NCTS_IE014,

Comment: Is this case only one giving the error?  Search code for XmlInclude.  Do you have the latest schema for parent.  Can't find the Message Type Schema (parent of EF15, IE015).  I suspect the parent has an inherited class and the class IE015 has the XmlInclude and the EF15 doesn't.

Comment: There is no just "XmlInclude" anywhere in the code. What  files should I give you ? What do you mean the parent of EF15. Sorry but I am try to learn because I have no knowledge how the xml,xsd etc are working, this is something new for me.

Comment: You are missing an XmlInclude.  There is a base class and inherited class.  The xmlInclude needs to be added above the base class of EF15.

Comment: Is there a cast?  I need to see the method MessageHelper.GetTestMessageType().

Comment: internal static MessageProcessorServiceTest.MessageType GetTestMessageType(MessageTypeIcisNet type)
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                case MessageTypeIcisNet.IE507:
                    return MessageProcessorServiceTest.MessageType.ECS_IE507;
                case MessageTypeIcisNet.IE515:
                    return MessageProcessorServiceTest.MessageType.ECS_IE515;
....   case MessageTypeIcisNet.EF15:
                    return MessageProcessorServiceTest.MessageType.EMCS_EF15;

Comment: That is exactly what I was expect.  Your class is EF15AType but the code is showing EMCS_EF15.  So there is a cast between the two types which is causing the XmlInclude.  Where is EMCS_EF15 defined in the code?  We also need to look at DigitallySignedMessage = new DigitallySignedMessage() { isXmlString = false, messageType = "EMCS_EF15", xmlMessage = new xmlMessage() { EF15A = new EF15A()}

Comment: I think I understand your confusion. When I call the submitNTCS I give as parameter MessageTypeIcisNet.EF15( MessageTypeIcisNet is just an enum). Now inside SubmitNTCS I call the MessageHelper.GetTestMessageType(type) (in our case type = EF15)  where the GetTestMessageType is a static class that it return the correct value of the name of the message that I try to send (in this case case MessageTypeIcisNet.EF15:
     return MessageProcessorServiceTest.MessageType.EMCS_EF15; ) . As for the EMCS_EF15 is just a text  which is send inside the XMLMessage  ( messageType="EMCS_EF15" )

Comment: I'm not confused.  The xsd tool created "public partial class EF15AType"  You have "EF15 ef15Msg = emcs.CreateEF15();"  Somehow the EF15 is getting cast to EF15AType.  The casting is causing the XmlInclude error.  Both pieces of code should be referencing the same class without casting.  Or you need to add an XmlInclude.

Comment: I think this needs to be changed from : "EF15 ef15Msg = emcs.CreateEF15();"  to "EF15AType ef15Msg = emcs.CreateEF15();"  This will create errors that also need to be changed.

Comment: You need to deserialize the string EMCS_EF15 to the Class EF15AType.  The string EMCS_EF15 is be cast (instead of deserialize) which is why you are getting xsi:type="xsd:string" and the XmlInclude error.  You should not have two objects EF15A and EMCS_EF15.

Comment: when I change EF15 ef15Msg = emcs.CreateEF15();" to "EF15AType ef15Msg = emcs.CreateEF15(); it gives me an error Cannot implicitly convert type Ektelonistis.EMCS.Operations.EF15.EF15' to Ektelonistis.EMCS.Messages.EF15.EF15AType" Maybe this helps

Comment: Do not have all the answers.  Two days ago I updated some of my code above to solvesome of the issues.  Instead of parsing the xml string I set parameters.  If you click on the link "edited two days ago" you will see the changes.  I need to see the entire EF15 class to understand the issue.  I think the answer is to make the class EF15AType "partial" and change your class EF15 to EF15Type partial.