# Namespace in a webservices soap in C#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, namespaces

I don't know how to modify the namespace in an xml of my web services SOAP.

I am doing web services SOAP in VS 2022 C# Standard and I have the request xml like this:

[image]

I need to it see like this:

[image]

The namespace pgim is necessary. How can I transform my xml?

Comment: Why?  Those two documents look equivalent.  The first one just uses a default namespace.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
Please edit your original question and provide the following:
(1) Well-formed XML sample. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: See my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77117283/cannot-send-correct-soap-message-in-c-sharp/77125962#77125962