# JAX-WS generated service VS WCF - Contract Filter Mismatch

Tags: c#, .net, soap, wsdl

So, in my company we have this scenario where we need to stop using one of the services one of our vendor system's is currently using.
Our company already stated we're not paying to the vendor a change that could make our lives easier.

Anyway, the problem is that the original service we're using was created in Java.
The wsdl looks something like this (this is just part of the file. I replaced some sensitive information)

```
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="urn:****" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="urn:****" name="Service">
<types>
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import namespace="urn:****" schemaLocation="****?xsd=1"/>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import namespace="urn:****" schemaLocation="****?xsd=2"/>
    </xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="GetStagedOrderId">
    <part name="GetStagedOrderIdRequest" element="tns:GetStagedOrderIdRequest"/>
</message>
<message name="GetStagedOrderIdResponse">
    <part name="GetStagedOrderIdResponse" element="tns:GetStagedOrderIdResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="GetStagedOrderIdFaultMessage">
    <part name="fault" element="tns:GetStagedOrderIdFault"/>
</message>  
<portType name="PortName">
    <operation name="GetStagedOrderId">
        <input wsam:Action="urn:****:PortName:GetStagedOrderIdRequest" message="tns:GetStagedOrderId"/>
        <output wsam:Action="urn:****:PortName:GetStagedOrderIdResponse" message="tns:GetStagedOrderIdResponse"/>
        <fault message="tns:GetStagedOrderIdFaultMessage" name="GetStagedOrderIdFaultMessage" wsam:Action="urn:****:PortName:GetStagedOrderId:Fault:GetStagedOrderIdFaultMessage"/>
        <fault message="tns:InvalidMessageFaultMessage" name="InvalidMessageFaultMessage" wsam:Action="urn:****:PortName:GetStagedOrderId:Fault:InvalidMessageFaultMessage"/>
        <fault message="tns:ServiceFaultMessage" name="ServiceFaultMessage" wsam:Action="urn:****:PortName:GetStagedOrderId:Fault:ServiceFaultMessage"/>
    </operation>        
</portType>
<binding name="PortNameBinding" type="tns:PortName">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <operation name="GetStagedOrderId">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </output>
        <fault name="GetStagedOrderIdFaultMessage">
            <soap:fault name="GetStagedOrderIdFaultMessage" use="literal"/>
        </fault>
        <fault name="InvalidMessageFaultMessage">
            <soap:fault name="InvalidMessageFaultMessage" use="literal"/>
        </fault>
        <fault name="ServiceFaultMessage">
            <soap:fault name="ServiceFaultMessage" use="literal"/>
        </fault>
    </operation>        
</binding>
<service name="Service">
    <port name="PortName" binding="tns:PortNameBinding">
        <soap:address location="****"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

Now, since we cannot make the vendor to update the software, a team in the company came up with the idea of replacing this service with another written in .NET (we must end up deploying this to the cloud), and when they started doing some tests when pointing to this new service, they start getting an error of this type:

> The message with action cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch...

By checking the WSDL of that new service they created, I can see it was like this:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:i0="urn:****" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="Bridge" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BasicHttpsBinding_IBridge_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:TransportToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:TransportToken>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Basic256/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Strict/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:TransportBinding>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsdl:import namespace="urn:****" location="https://localhost/Bridge/Bridge.svc?wsdl=wsdl0"/>
<wsdl:types/>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IBridge" type="i0:IBridge">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="DoWork">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:****/IBridge/DoWork" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetStagedOrderId">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:****/IBridge/GetStagedOrderId" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_IBridge" type="i0:IBridge">
    <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#BasicHttpsBinding_IBridge_policy"/>
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="DoWork">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:****/IBridge/DoWork" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetStagedOrderId">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:****/IBridge/GetStagedOrderId" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="Bridge">
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IBridge" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IBridge">
        <soap:address location="http://cpc-aleja-t7gr2/Bridge/Bridge.svc"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpsBinding_IBridge" binding="tns:BasicHttpsBinding_IBridge">
        <soap:address location="https://localhost/Bridge/Bridge.svc"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service></wsdl:definitions>
```

I'm not an expert in SOAP, to be honest, but from what I've been reading (and it looks obvious) is that the contracts of the original and the new one are nothing alike. We wanted to test first with only one method (the GetStagedOrderId), but got the error described above.

I tried to replicate this error by creating some services locally, and I only got it when I changed the endpoint URL to another service that didn't have the method I tried to call, which is pretty much what we're trying to do with the vendor's system.

We have some environment variables we can change and one of them are those endpoints URLs.

The real question here is:

Is there some way to create a new service with a similar contract that can allow us to consume the new service from the vendor's system?

.NET is creating the WSDL very differently, changing the names of the messages (by adding the interface and namespace) and I think that's part of the issue.

Do you know about some mechanism that can let me create a service with the same contract as the original?

Thanks.

Comment: You are missing the prefixes which are uses t specify which schema should be use to validate the xml.  So the validation of the xml is failing.  Add the prefixed.  See my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77117283/cannot-send-correct-soap-message-in-c-sharp/77125962#77125962

Comment: Hey @jdweng, if you're talking about the first XML file, that's exactly how the original service was created. I'm actually looking for a way to reproduce that, but .NET is generating the definition with the prefixes. The original one doesn't have them and it's currently working.

Comment: The namespaces need to be empty.String instead of the URL in the classes.  I think just removing the XmlSerializerNamespaces should give results.